# Returns memory location instead of string <function Welcome.greeting at 0x000001EDCC8130D8>

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to import a function from another class on another file.

When I print it out I get the memory location of the file(I think)

Here is my code:

first_app.py

```
class Welcome:

    def greeting(self):
        
        return 'Hello There'
```

second_app.py

```
from first_app import Welcome  #imports the class


    def answer():
        reply = Welcome.greeting #access greeting function
        print('Meeting')
        print(reply) #prints <function Welcome.greeting at 0x000001EDCC8130D8>
        print('Thank you')
    
    answer()
```

then when I run second_app.py, this is output

```
Meeting
<function Welcome.greeting at 0x000001EDCC8130D8>
Thank you
```

Where as it it was the string it would be

```
Meeting
Hello There
Thank you
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You are getting the string representation of the function. That is because you assigned the function to taht variable, `reply = Welcome.greeting`. You need to *call the function*.

Comment: Note what you are trying to do doesn't make a lot of sense. Why use a class *at all*? Your method uses no internal state, it should just be a function if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function/method, like this:

```
reply = Welcome().greeting()
```

Now `reply` will contain the string that you expect.

The parentheses following `Welcome()` tell Python to create an instance of class `Welcome`.

The second set of parentheses tell Python to call the function `greeting()`, i.e. to execute it. Without these you are simply referencing the function and the default output of `print()` is the function name and it's memory location.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think I would have to do a double call. I'll mark correct after the time limit.

Comment: It's not really a double call, the first is to instantiate an instance of the object of the class. The second is the function call. Usually you would bind the instantiated object to a variable name so that it can be used again later, e.g. `w =Welcome()` creates a `Welcome` object and binds it to name `w`. Then the method/function `greeting()` is called on object `w`.

Comment: You should probably accept this answer if you're happy with it.